# Yii2 SMTP, почему почта приходит не от имени(почты) пользователя

Tags: yii2, smtp

я использую стандартную contactForm модель, для связи пользователя с нами.

мои нистройки в main-local.php

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => 'mygmail@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'password',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
```

модель отправки почты

```
public function sendEmail($email)
    {
        return Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setFrom($this->email)
            ->setSubject($this->subject)
            ->setTextBody($this->body)
            ->send();
    }
```

```
public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Спасибо, что связались с нами. Мы ответим вам как можно скорее.');
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'При отправке вашего сообщения произошла ошибка.');
            }

            return $this->refresh();
        } else {
            return $this->render('contact', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Все работает но когда пользователь заполняет форму и отправляет, то почта приходит не от его имени(почты) , а от моей. Будто я пишу сам себе.
Как это исправить?

Comment: проверить переменные ` ->setTo($email) ->setFrom($this->email)` причину, почему они одинаковые...

Comment: Там приходят разные данные. данная setTo, setFrom -> разные почты